# FQH Edge Theory as decoupled chiral bosons

Tags: topological-order, quantum-hall-effect

The action describing the edge theory of the Fractional Quantum Hall effect is 
given by 
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}t \left[ K_{IJ} \ \partial_{t}\phi_{RI} \partial_{x}\phi_{RJ} - V_{IJ} \partial_{x}\phi_{RI}\partial_{x}\phi_{RJ} \right]
\end{equation}
for scalar fields $\phi_{RI}$ with $I=1....dim(K)$ and some symmetric,invertible matrix K and some positive definite, symmetric "velocity matrix" V.

The equations of motion for the fields read 
\begin{equation}
\partial_{t}\partial_{x} K_{IJ}\phi_{RJ} - \partial_{x}^{2}V_{IJ}\phi_{RJ} = 0.
\end{equation}
This smells already
 a lot like the chiral boson theory in 1+1D Minkowski space
which this action is supposed to be equivalent to. However I do not see the transformation that "decouples" the fields. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 2):

See eqn. 3.70 in my paper:
*Topological Orders and Edge Excitations in FQH States* ,
Advances in Physics 44, 405 (1995). ( http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9506066. )