# Equivalent Chern Simons Theories

Tags: topological-order, quantum-hall-effect

This is a follow-up question to [FQH Edge Theory as decoupled chiral bosons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98235/fqh-edge-theory-as-decoupled-chiral-bosons) .

The document that I will be refering to is http://dao.mit.edu/~wen/pub/toprev.pdf .

On page 14 in Eq.(2.33) the author argues that two Chern-Simons theories describe the same "Fractional quantum hall physics" when the K-matrices are the same up to conjugation with a SL(n,Z)-matrix. Also the charge vector of the two theories has to transform in a specific way.

At the bottom of page 31 the author outlines a way to simultaneously diagonalizes the K-Matrix and the V-Matrix in the edge theory. Here however there doesn't seem to be a restriction that the conjugation matrices need to be in SL(n,Z).

So I am wondering whether one may "accidentaly" perform a transformation on the fields that may leed to a theory describing a different fractional quantum hall state?

For example we choose $K=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$
to describe a $\nu=2/3$ state. We diagonalize the matrix by conjugating it first with $\Lambda_{1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{matrix} \right)$ and then with $\Lambda_{2}=\left( \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$. 
This yields a new K-Matrix K'=diag(1,-1). Then I am performing a Lorentz transformation that leaves K invariant and diagonalizes V. However none of these matrices is in SL(2,Z). 
(Also generically $U^{T}=U^{-1}$ is false in SL(2,Z).)

I would be very happy if someone could clear up this confusion for me:)

I am looking forward to your responses.